# d3 onmouseover path event selects area under the line

Tags: d3.js, svg

I would like to mouseover a path and have the line selected to change its color.

```
svg.append("svg:path")
    .style( {
        "fill": "orange",
        "stroke": "cyan",
        "stroke-width": "5",
    } )
    .attr("d", "M 121.5, 268.5 A 994.15, 994.15 0 0, 1 514.8, 348.3")
    .on ("mouseover", function (d) {
        d3.select(this).style( "stroke", "green" ) } )
    .on ("mouseout", function (d) {
        d3.select(this).style( "stroke", "cyan" ) } );
```

But as demonstrated in the fiddle the path is selected even when I mouse over the area under the curve (i.e. the orange area in the fiddle). Instead I would like for the line to change its color only when the mouse moves over the cyan line.

[Fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/m1myb4Lj/)

Comment: this can be done by giving the fill as none like this
http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/aes29q57/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way will probably be using [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) to restrict which parts of the element may become the target of mouse events. This could be done by either setting the CSS style:

```
.style("pointer-events", "stroke")
```

or by setting the attribute

```
.attr("pointer-events", "stroke")
```

The following snippet implements an example of both ways:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 555)
    .attr("height", 500)
 .style( "border", "1px solid #0000ff")
    .append("g")

svg.append("svg:path")
    .style( {
     "fill": "orange",
     "stroke": "cyan",
     "stroke-width": "5",
        "pointer-events": "stroke"
 } )
    .attr("d", "M 121.5, 268.5 A 994.15, 994.15 0 0, 1 514.8, 348.3")
 .on ("mouseover", function (d)
 {
     d3.select(this)
         .style( "stroke", "green" )
 } )
 .on ("mouseout", function (d)
 {
     d3.select(this)
         .style( "stroke", "cyan" )
 } )
 ;

svg.append("svg:path")
    .style( {
     "fill": "orange",
     "stroke": "cyan",
     "stroke-width": "5"
 } )
    .attr("d", "M 70.4, 388.25 A 784.8, 784.8 0 0, 1 384.7, 428.2")
    .attr("pointer-events", "stroke")
 .on ("mouseover", function (d)
 {
     d3.select(this)
         .style( "stroke", "green" )
 } )
 .on ("mouseout", function (d)
 {
     d3.select(this)
         .style( "stroke", "cyan" )
 } )
 ;

svg.append("svg:path")
    .style( {
     "fill": "orange",
     "stroke": "cyan",
     "stroke-width": "5",
        "pointer-events": "stroke"
 } )
    .attr("d", "M 384.7, 428.2 A 490.5, 490.5 0 0, 1 501.8, 268.5")
 .on ("mouseover", function (d)
 {
     d3.select(this)
         .style( "stroke", "green" )
 } )
 .on ("mouseout", function (d)
 {
     d3.select(this)
         .style( "stroke", "cyan" )
 } )
 ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**One way** is to make the fill none like this

```
svg.append("svg:path")
    .style( {
        "fill": "none",//make it none
        "stroke": "cyan",
        "stroke-width": "5",
    } )
    .attr("d", "M 121.5, 268.5 A 994.15, 994.15 0 0, 1 514.8, 348.3")
    .on ("mouseover", function (d)
    {
        d3.select(this)
            .style( "stroke", "green" )
    } )
    .on ("mouseout", function (d)
    {
        d3.select(this)
            .style( "stroke", "cyan" )
    } )
    ;
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/aes29q57/)

**Another way** in case you need the orange fill.

Append a new path below the old path something like this:

```
//add a dummy path with fill orange but no listeners
svg.append("svg:path")
    .style( {
        "fill": "orange",
        "stroke": "cyan",
        "stroke-width": "5",
    } )
    .attr("d", "M 121.5, 268.5 A 994.15, 994.15 0 0, 1 514.8, 348.3");
    //add a new path with fill none so that its over the other path

svg.append("svg:path")
    .style( {
        "fill": "none",
        "stroke": "cyan",
        "stroke-width": "5",
    } )
    .attr("d", "M 121.5, 268.5 A 994.15, 994.15 0 0, 1 514.8, 348.3")
    .on ("mouseover", function (d)
    {
        d3.select(this)
            .style( "stroke", "green" )
    } )
    .on ("mouseout", function (d)
    {
        d3.select(this)
            .style( "stroke", "cyan" )
    } )
    ;
```

Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/aes29q57/3/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my code I actually had `fill: none` and only used `fill:orange` for illustrative purposes. There must be something else in my code that prevents this from happening.